# webview is showing white screen for android 4.0 while it is working well on android 2.3

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, android-relativelayout

I am using a web view. It is working very fine on android 2.3. but it is showing a white screen as background in android 4.0. I checked for the data and data is coming on screen but automatically a white background is coming at the place of my given background. I also tried to make this white background as transparent but it is not working for android 4.0.
    I am providing code related to my problem.
    this is webView.xml

```
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/backButtonZodiacSign"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.09"
                        android:contentDescription="@drawable/back3"
                        android:src="@drawable/back3" />

                    <ScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/zodiac_calender_scroll"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.91" >`<WebView
                                android:id="@+id/webViewZodiacCalender"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                                android:layerType="software"
                                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/zodiac_calender_relative"
                                 />

                    </ScrollView>

                </LinearLayout>
```

And activity file->here html data is coming dynamically from other activity.

```
            String sign = null;
                sign = savedInstanceState.getString("zodiacSign");
                zordic_calender_sign = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zodiac_calender_sign);
                zordic_calender_sign.setText(sign.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                        + sign.substring(1));

                image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.zodiac_calender_image);
                String uriZodiacSign = "drawable/" + sign;
                int imageZodiacSign = getResources().getIdentifier(uriZodiacSign, null,
                        getPackageName());
                Drawable drawableZodiacSign = getResources().getDrawable(
                        imageZodiacSign);
                image.setImageDrawable(drawableZodiacSign);

                webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewZodiacCalender);
                backButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.backButtonZodiacSign);

                webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" + sign + ".html");
```

Please help me.... :(

Comment: Can you post the value of sign String? Maybe you have some missing or invalid html

Comment: I am passing some .html file dynamically by this sign variable and using that(sign) to make this url complete to call that particular  .html file.

Comment: Are you sure the file is html valid and is accessible/readable?
Also, can you remove "android:layout_below="@+id/zodiac_calender_relative" from webview? Seems unrelated considering you have the webview in a scrollview.

Comment: Hello Gunar, First of all thanks to show your interest in my problem. About that html file, these files are valid and readable. If you change their color from html in that case text are showing on white background. But i don't want to show text on white background.Another one I removed "android:layout_below="@+id/zodiac_calender_relative" from webview  and then tried to run but still it is not working as required.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, then you're having a webview displaying some content that uses a white (or at least close to white) font. For this reason you need the transparent background.

First of all make sure the webview is in a layout with any color you need, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/sample_back" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Next, indeed, it seems the background color specified from XML doesn't get into account so you could call explicitly setBackgroundColor. Something like below:

```
webContainer = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webContainer);
webContainer.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
webContainer.loadUrl("the_url_to_load");
```

Would that help?

Answer (score -1):

Use android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in manifest file for Android 4.0 versions or else it will show white screen.

Comment: Hello Ramji, I have already put this in manifest with activity registration block. But it is not working. One more thing this is working for one screen in 4.0 but same code is not giving required result for second screen.